# Nbomber How to execute steps just one time

Tags: c#, load-testing

I'm using NBomber for load testing. Is there a way to execute steps just one time? (or exactly n times)

I've found this:
 `context.StopScenario(context.ScenarioInfo.ScenarioName, "Stop Reason");`
But it doesn't seem to work, the statistics show 0 requests. Maybe I’m doing something wrong.

Here my code:

```
[Test]
public void METHOD()
{
    var step2 = Step.Create("step 2", timeout: TimeSpan.FromHours(1), execute: async context =>
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

            context.Logger.Information("step 2 is invoked!!!");

            return Response.Ok();
        }
        finally
        {
            context.StopScenario(context.ScenarioInfo.ScenarioName, "Executed 1 time ended");
        }
    });

    var scenario = ScenarioBuilder.CreateScenario("hello_world", step2).WithoutWarmUp()
        .WithLoadSimulations(Simulation.KeepConstant(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50)));

    NBomberRunner.RegisterScenarios(scenario).Run();
}
```

And the statistics:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Anton Moldovan.

The correct way to do this is checking the `context.InvocationCount`

The above code will be:

```
var step2 = Step.Create("step 2", timeout: TimeSpan.FromHours(1), execute: async context =>
{
    if (context.InvocationCount > 1)//Here we check How many times it has been executed
    {
        context.StopScenario(context.ScenarioInfo.ScenarioName, "Executed 1 time.");
    }

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    context.Logger.Information("step 2 is invoked!!!");

    return Response.Ok();
});

var scenario = ScenarioBuilder.CreateScenario("hello_world", step2).WithoutWarmUp()
    .WithLoadSimulations(Simulation.KeepConstant(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50)));

NBomberRunner.RegisterScenarios(scenario).Run();
```